# How to pass an array object into a constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I have an array object in my class. I would like to pass in a null array object of size 3 as a default for a parameterless constructor.

ex:

```
public class List{
    private String  name;
    private People[] names; default value array of names objects of size 6
public List(String name, People[] array ){
     this.name = name;
     this.names = array
    }
public List(){
    this("Sam",**[what would I put here]**);
}
}
```

Comment: BTW it’s a bad idea to name your classes the same as classes from the JDK, especially ones from java.util like List, because it leads to confusion.

Comment: That wasn't the question, but the external initialization is ugly. I would recommend defining another constructor, `MyList(String name)`, which initializes `this.names` with `new Person[] {null, null, null}`. Otherwise is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66297524/how-to-pass-an-array-object-into-a-constructor/66316801#66316801) the second best solution.

Comment: Oh yea, I just needed to make up something to convey the concept. I would never create a class called 'List'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `new SomeType [ size ]`

To create an empty array of a certain size, use `new` followed by the data type, and then square brackets enclosing the desired size of the array.

```
new SomeType [ size ]
```

Like this:

```
new Person [ 3 ]
```

So your problem line would be:

```
this( "Sam" , new Person [ 3 ] ) ;
```

The SPACE characters are ignored by Java. You may include them or omit them as a matter of preference.

```
this("Sam",new Person[3]);
```

Example code:

```java
package work.basil.example.lister;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyList
{
    private String name;
    private Person[] persons; //  default value array of names objects of size 3.

    public MyList ( final String name , final Person[] arrayOfPersons )
    {
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull( name ) ;
        this.persons = Objects.requireNonNull( arrayOfPersons );
    }

    public MyList ( )
    {
        this( "Sam" , new Person[ 3 ] );  //  Your problem line, solved.
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "List{ " +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                " | persons=" + Arrays.toString( persons ) +
                " }";
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        MyList myList = new MyList();
        System.out.println( "myList = " + myList );
    }
}
```

When run.

> myList = List{ name='Sam' | persons=[null, null, null] }

---

By the way, `List` is a poor choice of name for a class. The class [`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) is bundled with Java, and is quite commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

*You could use a vararg for the array-object*

```
public MyList( String name, People ... array ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.names = array.length == 0 ? new Person[] {null, null, null} : array;
}

public MyList() {
    this( "Sam" );
}
```

so the array argument can be omitted for Your special case
this solution works, if the size of a passed array is always greater than 0